# Передача переменной из одной onclick-функции в другую

Tags: javascript, html

Для опыта создал две кликабельные кнопки. Идея такова - при нажатии на кнопку срабатывает onclick-функция, которая записывает в переменную определенное значение, которое возвращаем return-ом. При нажатии второй кнопки срабатывает другая onclick-функция, задача которой проверить, а было ли нажатие на основную кнопку.

Я написал, как я это себе представляю, но увы - код не работает. Ибо искомая функция *is not defined*. У меня складывается впечатление, что в onclick-функцию невозможно передать параметр со значением и прописать его в переменную уже в другой onclick-функции.

В глобальном плане, моя цель знать, был ли произведен клик по некому элементу DOM-а, дабы при клике на другой элемент у меня уже были некие данные ("да, нажатие было" / "нет, нажатия не было")

```js
document.querySelector(".button1").onclick = function foo() {
  var ifPress = true;
  return ifPress;
};
document.querySelector(".button2").onclick = function() {
  var check = foo();
  if (check === true) {
    console.log("Кнопка была нажата");
  } else {
    console.log("Кнопка не была нажата");
  }
};
```

```css
button  {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="button1">Нажми меня</button>
<button class="button2">Проверить нажатие по первой кнопке</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сохранить факт нажатия на кнопку можно просто в глобальной переменной, без каких-либо дополнительных функций:

```js
var firstButtonIsClicked = false;

document.querySelector(".button1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  firstButtonIsClicked = true;
});

document.querySelector(".button2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (firstButtonIsClicked) {
    console.log("Кнопка была нажата");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Кнопка не была нажата");
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="button1">Нажми меня</button>
<button class="button2">Проверить нажатие по первой кнопке</button>
```

---

Если не хочется засорять глобальную область видимости, можно обернуть код в "самовыполняющуюся функцию" (IIFE):

```js
(function() {
  var firstButtonIsClicked = false;

  document.querySelector(".button1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    firstButtonIsClicked = true;
  });

  document.querySelector(".button2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (firstButtonIsClicked) {
      console.log("Кнопка была нажата");
    }
    else {
      console.log("Кнопка не была нажата");
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<button class="button1">Нажми меня</button>
<button class="button2">Проверить нажатие по первой кнопке</button>
```

Или же хранить факт клика в самой кнопке (например, в dataset-е):

```js
document.querySelector(".button1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.dataset.isClicked = true;
});

document.querySelector(".button2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var firstButton = document.querySelector(".button1");
  if (firstButton.dataset.isClicked) {
    console.log("Кнопка была нажата");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Кнопка не была нажата");
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="button1">Нажми меня</button>
<button class="button2">Проверить нажатие по первой кнопке</button>
```

Comment: О, а ларчик то просто открывался, спасибо!

Comment: @ДмитрийБоргир на здоровье. Если ответ вас устраивает, не забудьте отметить его как подходящий

Comment: И спасибо за развернутый ответ, очень помогли. Теперь знаю, куда дальше двигаться.